# How to find the closest element in another column for each element in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

The situation is as follows.

I have two pandas dataframes:

- **df1**, which contains a column **"p1"** with 1895 rows of random numbers ranging from 2.805 to 3.035 (here are the first 20 rows):

```
         p1
0       2.910
1       2.885
2       2.875
3       2.855
4       2.910
5       2.870
6       2.850
7       2.875
8       2.865
9       2.875
10      2.890
11      2.910
12      2.965
13      2.955
14      2.935
15      2.905
16      2.900
17      2.905
18      2.970
19      2.940
```

- **df2**, which contains two columns, **"p2"** and **"h"**

```
    p2   h
0   2.7 256.88
1   2.8 253.52
2   2.9 250.18
3   3.0 246.86
4   3.1 243.55
```

The aim is to first loop through all rows in **df1** and find the closest element in **p2** for each row. e.g. for `p1[0] = 2.910`, the closest element is `p2[2] = 2.9`.

- Then, if these two values are the same, the output for that row is the corresponding value of **h**
- otherwise, the output is the average of the previous and subsequent values of **h**.

Going back to our example, the output for `p1[0]` should therefore be `(h[1]+h[3])/2`

I hope this all makes sense, this is my first question on here :). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the usage of `merge_asof`, notice the `allow_exact_matches=True` is default as True, for example 2.9 nearest is 2.9 in this case

```
df1=df1.sort_values('p1')
s1=pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_on='p1',right_on='p2',direction='backward')
s2=pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_on='p1',right_on='p2',direction='forward')
df1['Value']=(s1.h+s2.h)/2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works fine! Do you have any idea how I could include the p1 term in the final equation? e.g. for p1=2.805, the output in 'Value' is (s1.hfg+s2.hfg)/2 + 2.805 ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some test data
x1 = np.random.randint(0,100,10)
x2 = np.vstack([np.random.randint(0,100,10),np.random.normal(0,1,10)]).T

# Repeat the two vectors
X1 = np.tile(x1,(len(x2),1))
X2 = np.tile(x2[:,0],(len(x1),1))
distance = np.abs(X1 - X2.T)
closest_idx = np.argmin(distance,axis=0)

print(x2[closest_idx,1])
```